# How to use php to search if element already exists in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a website and when a user registers I want to check, if the entered `email` has already been used to `register` another account.

```
database: users
row: email
new email: $email_register
```

```php
$result = $pdo->prepare("IF email_register = ? IN email FROM users $same = TRUE");
$result->execute(array($email_register));   
$user = $result->fetch();
if($same == TRUE)
{
echo email already used;
}
else
{
#continue registration process
}
```

I want a way to know if the `email` is already in the db, and if it is, for the user to be sent back to the registration page with an error message `(error code transmitted via header)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no need for IF in the SQL query. Just write simple select statement like:

`Select email from users where email = 'example@example.com';`

if query return and result it means the email is already in database if not then you can continue to the registration process.

```
if($exist)
{
    return false; or you redirect to registration page whatever you want to do. 
}
#continue registration process
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that users should not have more than one account per email, an easy approach is to make the email column a unique key (or primary key) in the users table. This prevents an email being used more than once.

Comment: yeah, that way, you can ensure, that each email only exists once, but that does not notify the user that their email has already been used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
// check if email is taken already
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email_register = :email");
$stmt->execute([
    'email_register ' => $email
]);
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (isset($user) && !empty($user)){
    // Username already taken
   echo "email already used";
}else{
   //redirect to registration process
}
```